# Проблема с условием выхода из цикла while в Си

Tags: c

Написала программку для вычисления суммы бесконечного ряда с заданной пользователем точностью по формуле. Однако некорректно выполняется выход из цикла while. Читала, что сравнивать числа типа float не следует. Находила варианты с fabs |a-b|, но не смогла корректно реализовать. Пробовала выкрутиться с if-else - тоже не удалось. Как, все-таки, правильно прописать условие?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void){
float e=0, x=0, y=0.5772156649, n=0, Ei=0, sigma=0, tetha=0, sum=0, q=0, g=0, k=0, f=0, s=1, t=0;
 printf("Enter x=: \n");
  scanf("%f", &x);
   printf("Enter e=: \n");
    scanf("%f", &e);
     while (sigma<e){
      for (tetha=0; tetha<=n; ){
      t=s; //первое число факториала
      s=t+1; //второе число факториала
      tetha=t*s; //считаем факториал
      printf("t=%f, s=%f \n", t, s);
      }
    n++;
    q=pow(x, n); //числитель дроби
    f=n*tetha; //знаминатель дроби
    sigma=q/f; //считаем дробь
    sum=sum+sigma; //суммируем члены ряда
    g=log(x);
    k=y+log(x);
    Ei=k+sum;
    printf("tetha=%f, q=%f, f=%f,  sigma=%f, sum=%f, g=%f, k=%f, Ei=%f, y=%f, e=%f, x=%f \n", tetha, q, f, sigma, sum, g, k, Ei, y, e, x);
    if(n==10) break;
    }
     return 0;                          
}
```

[image: Формула]

Comment: Сравнивать float можно (смотря как) и нужно. В статьях говорится что проверять **на равенство** нежелательно (это синоним сравнивать), т.к. есть вероятность несовпадения. А сравнивать на больше и на меньше - можно.

Comment: Что означает некорректно? В чём именно проблема?

Comment: Программа прогоняет один цикл и выходит, но при этом условие не выполняется. Для значений x=: 0.5 e=: 0.001 получается sigma=0.25.

Comment: В языке С в заголовке цикла указывается условие *продолжения* цикла, а не условие *выхода* из цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика такая - слагаемые сначала большие, потому уменьшаются. Поэтому цикл должен выполняться, пока модуль слагаемого (sigma) больше допуска (у вас наоборот)

```
  while (fabs(sigma) >= e){
```

Кроме того,  есть моменты, которые не влияют непосредственно на правильность вычислений, но неоптимальны:

- вынесите вычисление постоянных членов `гамма+ln` за цикл (это начальное значение)
- избавьтесь от `q=pow(x, n);` - достаточно каждый раз умножать текущий числитель на `x`
- факториал не нужно вычислять каждый раз с самого начала - домножьте текущее значение на `n`